# Traceroute on android

Tags: android, traceroute, jpcap

I am a beginner on android platform, and I want to build a tracerouting app. So these are my queries:

1. Is it possible to make such an application in Android? if possible then guide me the way that I follow.
2. Does Android support low-level programming to capture ICMP packets? or do I need to add some kind of JAR (in java) or some other libraries to support this application?
3. In Java, there are JPCAP and docjar etc kind of libraries that we can import in our IDE or Eclipse so that Java support for making such kind of API's?

I need valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to just check for the `traceroute` Linux application, execute it, and parse its output.

Android has full networking support, however, Java doesn't expose an interface to alter the IP header. Hence, manually crafting ICMP packages is out of the question (JPCAP is no help here, since it relies on libpcap, which I suppose you won't find on any vanilla installation).

Another *possible* solution is to use the NDK and create a small library that handles the low-level number crunching. However, I'm not sure if the NDK would allow you to use `setsockopt`.

Comment: will give an exapmle

Answer (score 4):

It's quite late - but someone might see it.
i found this one and it worked for me:
https://github.com/olivierg13/TraceroutePing

Comment: Try and not post answer that are entirely in a link, because the content of your link may change. At the very least, you should try to post here some useful guideline to answer the question. Thanks.

Comment: This library is not working in Samsung S4 5.0 will you help me

Comment: If anyone is looking for how to tracert in Android or an app, [Network Analyzer][1] is pretty good. It has a few other functions as well. 

  [1]: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.techet.netanalyzerlite.an&gl=US

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/wangjing53406/traceroute-for-android) is working pretty well for me, you may have to filter out the string results.
To add this library, you have to download or clone the git repository and implement the folder "library" just as he does in the other module "app" for it to work properly.