# Android traceroute, ping, dnslookup

Tags: android, ping, traceroute, nslookup

I want to implement traceroute/ping/dns lookup in the my application.
For ping i use a ProcessBuilder:

```
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ping", "-c 1", host);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

But how can i use a traceroute and dns lookup? Is it possible without root? Thx.

Comment: Duplicated?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203374/traceroute-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the *traceroute* command. This command is essentially recursive *ping* with *TTL* (time to live) flag set. TTL does not have anything to do with time. Instead it's a hop counter. Each time the IP packet passes through a router or switch the TTL field is decremented by 1. This field is 8 bits long, so max hops would be 255.

This means that you can do your own traceroute with ping.

**Something like:**

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder;
for(int i = 100; i != 0; i--) {
  processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ping", "-c 1 -T " + i, host);
  /* do stuff here */
}
```